# Storage limit in production environment

Tags: community, data-storage

In one of the customer environment, data storage used is 3.5 GB which is 351% more than allocated limit (1 GB). We are not receiving any storage limit exceeded error, but the environment is very slow. Sometimes we even run into time limit exceeded to load a single page. Please see the following screenshot for reference.

[image: Storage limit snapshot of customer environment]
In developer or sandbox environment, as soon as we reached 1 GB limit we run into storage limit exceeded. Is there a reason why production environment is behaving differently? 
Also, can it be reason for the slowness of system.
I tried searching for it, but could not find any proper documentation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Parul

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is the reason for slowness, but I know that in our production environment we are able to exceed the limit without ever hitting a "hard limit". I believe that this is the case in all production orgs, I'd be interested in hearing anything to the contrary.
All that happens when we exceed is that we are charged more by Salesforce.

This is different from the sandboxes which will start to error usually around 110% and require cleared down.

It's probably worth your customer having a discussion with their account representative before they get hit by a bigger invoice than they are expecting. And/or perhaps there is some housekeeping that you can do to remove unneeded data.

Comment: I have seen instances where on exceeding the limit and creating a new record there has been an error but it's not a consistent cut off point. I can recreate it in a developer sandbox I have that has emails copied to it.

Comment: I used to see it a lot doing volume testing in sandboxes, we'd get to 110% or 120% and then it would just start consistently returning errors. My understanding (based on hearsay) is that this doesn't happen in Production orgs, and certainly I've seen the Production org significantly exceed the limit without any problem.

Comment: Salesforce.com will generally not stop you from adding data in your production environment. They do not want to stop production business from being conducted. However your SFDC AE will get notified that you are above your licensed data storage and come knocking for more $$$.

Comment: They have much stricter rules on the Sandboxes because that is not considered production environment, so they quickly cut you off in Sandboxes including Full Copy Sandboxes. That is why you see a descrpency between the % overages and the cutoff of adding new records.

Comment: Also you may see performance degradation in your reports, list views, queries, etc. because you have added data volumes that have crossed the Force.com Query Selectivity Thresholds.  This usually means you need to create custom indexes and update your list views / reports / SOQL to be selective. More details here: https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_query_search_optimization_developer_cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: We cannot clean up the data, as it is the production environment. Would have to check with salesforce for some solution. Also I still need to know can exceeding the limit beyond a certain point cause system to be pretty slow ?

Comment: I believe that having a lot of data can cause the system to be pretty slow - ie. if you have a table with a million rows it might be slower to work with than if it had a thousand rows. You can look to optimise queries, use indexes etc. to speed this up. I don't believe that exceeding the SF storage limit itself causes the system to be slower. I think it's likely that the two things: slowness and exceeding the limit - are both results of the same thing, having lots of data in your tables.

Comment: Salesforce article said that there will be no implications of data storage in production environment. Please see the link https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000213997&language=en_US