# Salesforce database storage is 3.8 GB out of 1 GB, hows that possible?

Tags: api, professional-edition, data-storage

I am using PE and was inserting custom object records through API, there were around 3 millions of record. I thought storage limit will exceed but instead it is using 382% of storage. Can any one let me know the reason behind this?
Also do I need take care of anything because of this?

Comment: Salesforce will not just have your org blocked because you are exceeding storage limits, but will charge you an additional cost if this is a permanent situation.

Comment: Thanks Robin! How soon they will start charging on this?

Comment: You should contact your account executive for that type of information.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce will not just have your org blocked because you are exceeding storage limits, but will charge you an additional cost if this is a permanent situation.

You should contact your **account executive** for more information.

EDIT: 
A [similar question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/76154/storage-limit-in-production-environment?rq=1) was posted here.

Comment: Though I have seen uploads via dataloader etc fail when orgs hit their limits, so I would be pro-active about addressing the issue...

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC: You would have seen these errors in a sandbox but if it is production - you will not see that error.